# Repeated custom UITableViewCell only draws last cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

In my UITableView, I have a few custom cells, and then one custom cell that needs to repeat 10 times, with a different value for a UILabel in each. Everything renders fine until I try to reuse my last custom cell multiple times. What happens is that the last cell draws correctly, but the previous 9 show up blank, with no split between cells.

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        cell = nameCell;
        break;
    case 1:
        cell = globalSettingsCell;
        break;
    case 2:
        cell = queueTypeCell;
        break;
    case 3:
        cell = starMinCell;
        break;
    case 4:
        cell = lengthMaxCell;
        break;
}

if (indexPath.row > 4) {
    cell = genreCell;
    genreLabel.text = [genres objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row - 5)];
}

return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use one cell (genreCell) for multiple indexPaths simultanously.

Answer (score 0):

You have only one identifier but more then one different cells? And I think you don't know how to reuse Cells correct.

Try something like this...

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier_1 = @"Cell_1";
static NSString *CellIdentifier_2 = @"Cell_2";
//...
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier_1]; 
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier_1] autorelease];
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier_2];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier_2] autorelease];
        }
        break;
}
```